# Get Model field as string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've just started recently been learning to the Django framework, and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to get a Django Model field as a string. The Model (MapArea) [successfully retrieves data from the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/), but I need to convert parts of the data to strings in order to parse its JSON-esque format into lists. The field I need to convert to a string is set as `streets = models.CharField(max_length=2000)`

Here is my Model class:

```
class MapArea(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)
    streets = models.CharField(max_length=2000)`

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    # Do stuff with a string of street data from the database
    def get_runways(streets):
        return streetList
```

Right now, I'm attempting to use a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) to call the method in my Model (MapArea), because I can't seem to figure out how to convert the data to a string on assignment:

```
@register.filter(name = 'get_streets')
def get_streets(obj, streets):
    return obj.get_streets(streets)
```

This is then being used my template as `{{ maparea|get_streets:maparea.streets }}`, which gives me the error `get_streets() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Ideally I'd like to just be able to convert the data before assigning streets. For example:

```
streets = get_streets(models.CharField(max_length=2000)) # Somehow converted to a string to use with the method
```

I'm not sure that's possible with the whole query Model system from what I've been attempting.

So my question is: how can I get the CharField data as a string to use it with my list conversion method (`get_streets()`) for use in my template?

Thank you in advance. I apologize if this is confusing. Sort of two issues go on here. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `streets` is a CharField, so whatever is in it is already a string -  no need for any template filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django, the db access on a model instance just looks like normal attribute access.  The ORM handles the db queries for you behind the scenes.

```
def get_runways(self):
    # you can directly access "self.streets" attribute on the model instance
    return something
```

If you are new to Django, but have some experience with Python already, you may have expected that accessing `self.streets` here would return a `models.CharField` instance.  But in fact it returns a string, because the base class `models.Model` does some processing of the fields defined on the subclass.

Comment: but when I use self.streets syntax it return value like this <QuerySet [<Obj: something here >]>', I want to get the text only :something here

Comment: @SaddamMeshaal Your use-case is obviously different, the OP's use case has `streets = models.CharField(max_length=2000)` i.e. a char column in database. I guess in your case streets is a relation (since you're getting a queryset).

Comment: thank you sir, I got it using get() function instead of filter in my return function